# Selecting rows in the table by specific mark

Tags: r

I have a huge data file. In one column I have a specific sequences of the big letters, which looks like "FAPYGTITSAKVMRTE". There are like 1000 rows of such sequences. Important for me is just to select those sequences which has atleast one "K" in the sequence. Rest of them I can just ignore. How to pick those sequences from whole data set ? If it's needed I can upload a data file somewhere.

Comment: This sounds like a job for perl/python and regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `grepl`

```
> set.seed(2)
> df <- data.frame(sequences=replicate(10, paste0(sample(LETTERS[7:12], 5, TRUE), collapse=""))) # example

>df[grepl("K", df$sequence), , drop = FALSE] # thanks to Henrik's comment
   sequences
1      HKJHL
3      JHKHI
7      GGKLJ
8      JLHKG
10     KLIJK
```

Comment: Why `apply(df, 1, ...)` instead of `sapply(df$sequences, ...)`? Seems more natural to me.

Comment: Do we need any `*pply`? `df[grepl("K", df$sequence), , drop = FALSE]`

Comment: Hahaha... seems like working. Thx guys. Really appreciate your help! Is there any way to show how grateful I am coz it's my first time on this forum.

Comment: Yes, there is!!! upvote the answer and accept it as the correct one by doing clik in the tick mark just below the score ;)